# Not able to understand the working of Pre-increment/ Pre-decrement in C++

Tags: c++, operators, pre-increment

Can someone please explain what is happening in the following code? (Taken from GeeksForGeeks)

```
int main(){
 int a = 10;
 ++a = 20; // works
 printf("a = %d", a);
 getchar();
 return 0;
}
```

What exactly is happening when the statement ++a = 20 is executed? Also, please clarify why this code fails in execution?

```
int main(){
    int a = 10;
    a++ = 20; // error 
    printf("a = %d", a);
    getchar();
    return 0;
 }
```

Code Taken From: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-40/

Comment: I believe this is undefined behaviour.

Comment: This *certainly* doesn't work in c.

Comment: @eof it doesn't work in python either. What's your point? No one here talked about C.

Comment: @tilz0R gcc gives an error on this. I guess that means it's not UB

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca This question was originally tagged `c` as well.

Comment: @eof, sorry about that, then :)

Answer (score 8):

When you do

```
++a = 20;
```

it's roughly equivalent to

```
a = a + 1;
a = 20;
```

But when you do

```
a++ = 20;
```

it's *roughly* equivalent to

```
int temp = a;
a = a + 1;
temp = 20;
```

*But* the variable `temp` doesn't really exist. The result of `a++` is something called an *rvalue* and those can't be assigned to. Rvalues are supposed to be on the *right hand side* of an assignment, not left hand side. (That's basically what the `l` and `r` in `lvalue` and `rvalue` comes from.)

See e.g. [this values category reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) for more information about lvalues and rvalues.

Answer (score 1):

The left operand of the assignment operator should be an lvalue.
The expression `++a` is an lvalue while `a++` is not and therefore it can't be the left operand of the assignment operator.

n3797-§ 5.3.3(p1):

> [...] The result is the updated operand; it is an lvalue [...]

Comment: Are you talking about C or C++? In C, AFAIK neither are lvalues.

Comment: @EOF; It's about C++. And yes in C++, `++a` is an lvalue.

Comment: @EOF; Added the reference.

Answer (score 1):

This is the difference between r and l values. If you would have compiled the 2nd code snippet with gcc you would have seen this:

> lvalue required as left operand of assignment

meaning, that `a++` is rvalue and not a lvalue as it should be if you want to assign something to it

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(){
 int a = 10;
 ++a = 20; // works
 printf("a = %d", a);
 getchar();
 return 0;
}
```

This is a c Language.
Explaining Line by line
**int main()** THIS line define an entry function called main which is expected to return a type integer(int)
int a = 10 declares a variable integer whose value is 10;
++a = 20; AT this point your code is incrementing the value of a by 1 before any operation is performed on a.
This means that, the value of a is incremented by 1 bfore a is assign the value of 20;....
the statement ++a = 20 is incorect in the sense that, a is 10 initially, and you increment it to 11 . Is like saying 11 = 20; this may not throw an error because the code line is not useful.
printf() is a c-method to print file to screen, passing a string "a = %d" tells the compiler to print a to a decimal number(%d).
getchar() is use to terminate the running program and return 0 is to forcefully tell the operating system that the code run successfully and return integer value 0.

```
int main(){
    int a = 10;
    a++ = 20; // error 
    printf("a = %d", a);
    getchar();
    return 0;
 }
```

This didn't at a++ = 20 because , right value increment perform the operation before it increment unlike ++a who increment before performing operation.
So this isn't possible and it never works because a is already 10, and you are saying the value ++ and assign 20, you can't assign a value to it, it should be the one calculating its own value. So the compiler will want to interprete is as variable a++ = 20, and ++ can not be a vaiable name. That's why it never work.

What is the essence of incrementation and decrementation in c....its useful for creating conditional statement e.g for loop, while statement etc. for example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
printf('THis is c-language');
}
```

or

```
int i = 0;
while(i < 4){
printf('THis is c-Language');
i++;
}
```

so therefore, following the programming rules and regulations, you are not allow to assign value to either a++ or ++a
they are for the compilers to manipulate, so never assign value to them.
Thank you.